# Regex para patrón con duplicados

Tags: regex

Estoy intentando montar una Regex que coincida con los siguientes patrones:

- Objeto `(123)`
- Objeto `(Abc)`
- Objeto `(Abc-123)`
- Objeto `(Ab-12)` Attr `(1_2_4)`

De tal manera que me detecte todo aquello que está entre paréntesis.

He probado con varias, las mayores aproximaciones han sido:

- `\([[:alnum:]]+\)` : El problema es que esta únicamente me detecta los caracteres alfanuméricos, lo cual es un problema, ya que si incluye cualquier otro carácter especial, `"-"`, `"_"`, etc. no los detecta.
- `\(.*)\)` / `\((.*)\)`: El problema con estas dos es que en el caso del último producto me detecta lo siguiente, Producto`(Ab-12) Attr (1_2_4)`.

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: `:alnum:` de que lenguaje de programacion es? ya intentaste con `\([[:alnum:\-_]]+\)`?

Comment: Intenta agregarle un signo de interrogación `\((.*?)\)`

Comment: Quieres todo lo que está DENTRO de los paréntesis, pero solo es son antecedidos por las palabras "Objeto" y/o "Attr" ???

Comment: @Yussef quiero incluir únicamente las cadenas de carácteres que haya entre paréntesis, independientemente de lo que haya fuera. Es decir si tengo `(123) str (234) str (abc) str`, solo tendría que cogerme todo aquello que esté entre paréntesis, es decir, `(123)`, `(234)` y `(abc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías agregar los caracteres que quisieras a la clase de caracteres

```
\([[:alnum:]\-_]+\)
```

- El `-` hay que escaparlo

O que coincida con alfanuméricos y signos de puntuación usando la clase POSIX `punct`

```
\([[:alnum:][:punct:]]+\)
```

O también usando `\w` que coincide con `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```
\([\w\-]+\)
```

O hacer que `.*` o `.+` coincidan con lo menos posible usando `.*?` o `.+?` respectivamente

```
\(.+?\)
```

O coincidir con cualquier caracter que no sea un `)`

```
\([^)]+\)
```

O con cualquier caracter que no sea un `(` ni un `)`

```
\([^()]+\)
```

Comment: Esta me va perfecto: `\([^)]+\)`, era justo lo que buscaba.

Comment: En ese caso, cuidado con algo como `"(a) (xx (b)"` si puede presentarse un paréntesis desbalanceado en tu texto

Comment: Es cierto, en este caso prefiero que prevalezca la legibilidad del código, no creo que se dé un caso tan concreto y en caso de serlo, imagino que será más un error humano, lo más probable es que solo se incluyan caracteres alfanuméricos y tal vez guiones.

Answer (score 0):

Para encontrar algo que está "dentro de" debes ocupar `lookaround`, aquí te dejo un [tutorial](https://es.javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind)

Basicamente se ocupa `?<=` y `?=` para enmarcar el contenido

```js
let regex = /(?<=\()([^\)]+)(?=\))/g


pruebas = [
"Objeto (123)" ,
"Objeto (Abc)", 
"Objeto (Abc-123)", 
"Objeto (Ab-12) Attr (1_2_4)", 
"Producto(Ab-12) Attr (1_2_4)"]; 

for (let p of pruebas) {
    console.log(p.match(regex));
    
}
```

Ahora si quieres incluir los paréntesis lo anterior no es necesario

```js
let regex = /\(([^\)]+)\)/g
pruebas = [
"Objeto (123)" ,
"Objeto (Abc)", 
"Objeto (Abc-123)", 
"Objeto (Ab-12) Attr (1_2_4)", 
"Producto(Ab-12) Attr (1_2_4)"]; 

for (let p of pruebas) {
    console.log(p.match(regex));

}
```